# Как получить имя того, кто запустил процесс? C#

Tags: c#, winforms

В диспетчере задач есть такой столбец "Пользователь" где пишется от кого запущен, админ или пользв, как вывести это?
Пока что я смог только получать ID 1 или 0 (1-юзер, 0- админ), а нужно чтоб выдавало кто запустил процесс.
Полная часть кода

**UPD_1**

```
 Process[] proces; 
    private void GetProcesses() 
    {
            ListViewItem row;
              proces = Process.GetProcesses();
                if (Convert.ToInt32(label2.Text) != proces.Length) 
                      {
                  LstProc.Items.Clear();
                  for (int i = 0; i < proces.Length; i++)
                      {
                 row = new ListViewItem(proces[i].ProcessName); 
                  row.SubItems.Add((proces[i].VirtualMemorySize64 / 2048).ToString() + " КБ");
                    row.SubItems.Add("Работает");
                      row.SubItems.Add(proces[i].SessionId.ToString());

                     LstProc.Items.Add(row);
                       List<ListViewItem> arrayToDelete = new List<ListViewItem>();
                          for (int j = 0; j < LstProc.Items.Count; j++)
                             if (LstProc.Items[j].SubItems[2].Text == "*")
                               arrayToDelete.Add(LstProc.Items[j]);
                                 foreach (ListViewItem delete in arrayToDelete)
                                    LstProc.Items.Remove(delete);
                                        }
                                        label2.Text = proces.Length.ToString();
                                        }
                  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получить все процессы можно так:

```
        using System.Management;
        ...

        ManagementObjectSearcher Processes = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
        foreach (ManagementObject Process in Processes.Get())
        {
            if (Process["ExecutablePath"] != null)
            {
                string[] OwnerInfo = new string[2];
                Process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", OwnerInfo);
                string nameProc = Path.GetFileName(Process["ExecutablePath"].ToString());
                string ownerProc = OwnerInfo[0];                  
            }
        }
```

Оригинал: https://stackoverflow.com/a/300535/7099599

**Update 1**

В твоем коде можно так (это и есть с помощью Win32 API):

```
        List<ListViewItem> itemProc = new List<ListViewItem>(); // список процессов с параметрами
        ManagementObjectSearcher Processes = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_Process");
        foreach (ManagementObject Process in Processes.Get())
        {
            if (Process["ExecutablePath"] != null)
            {
                row = new ListViewItem(Path.GetFileName(Process["ExecutablePath"].ToString()));
                string[] OwnerInfo = new string[2];
                Process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", OwnerInfo);
                //сразу добавляем массив параметров
                row.SubItems.AddRange(new string[]
                {
                    (Int64.Parse(Process["VirtualSize"].ToString()) / 1024).ToString(), // память
                    "Работает", // статус
                    Process["SessionId"].ToString(), // id сессии
                    OwnerInfo[0] // имя владельца
                });
                itemProc.Add(row);
            }
        }
        itemProc.RemoveAll(x => x.SubItems[2].Text == "*"); // эта строка вместо всей той второй части с удалением
        LstProc.Items.AddRange(itemProc.ToArray()); // теперь очищенный список itemProc передается в ListView
```

Comment: nameProc - это имя владельца процесса и есть) Тут другой вопрос тогда - нужно конкретно имя владельца или его принадлежность к группе админа/юзера?

Comment: Что вообще этот код делает - я создал лист вью, туда вывожу список процессов, память занимаемую ими, статус процесса  и ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЬ(его я не могу вывести) .
Я вообще пишу диспетчер задач

Comment: Хм, вроде все работает, но мой диспетчер ведет себя странно теперь, имя пользователя выводится все нормально, только вот скрол боковой уходит в низ, как будто добавляется 30 процессов в секунду, скрол расширяется больше и больше, кнопки мои вообще отказали, не работают теперь)Возможно это с таймером что-то не то, блин добавил одно, а получилось еще тысяча и одна ошибка :D Больше костылей пожалуйста

Comment: Вывод общего количества - выводи itemProc.Count(). А так хорошо бы прикрутить логгер и посмотреть, что там происходит. Возможно, где-то в цикле Processes.Get() повторяется.

Comment: Можно поподробней про иметПроц.каунт?) 
И как логер прикрутить,?

Comment: itemProc.Count - количество элементов в списке itemProc (в нашем случае это и есть количество процессов). А логгер - используй какой-нибудь nuget пакет для этого (в обозревателе решения правой кнопкой мыши по ссылкам - управление пакетами Nuget). Я использую NLog

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System.Management;
    ....
        string[] propertiesToSelect = new[] { "Handle", "ProcessId" };
        SelectQuery processQuery = new SelectQuery("Win32_Process", "Name = 'origin.exe'", propertiesToSelect); // тут нужно подставить имя процесса

        using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(processQuery))
        using (ManagementObjectCollection processes = searcher.Get())
            foreach (ManagementObject process in processes)
            {
                object[] outParameters = new object[2];
                uint result = (uint)process.InvokeMethod("GetOwner", outParameters);

                if (result == 0)
                {
                    string user = (string)outParameters[0]; //тут получаем имя

                    // дальше делаем че надо
                }
                else
                {
                    // тут код если GetOwner не сработал
                }
            }
```

original
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566835/how-to-get-the-user-name-or-owner-of-a-process-in-net/9013685#9013685

Comment: Кажется, кто-то забыл ссылку на оригинал ответа указать. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9013685/7099599